# Call JavaScript window method in WebView React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, webview

I have a `React Native project` in which I use a `WebView from react-native-webview`. I also have a `ReactJS project` inside the main one which I show it in the `Webview`.

My problem is at it follows:

I have the next function inside a file called `player.player`:

```
  window.Play = async function () {
  window.alert('1111')
  const instrument = await loadInstrument();

  const transpose = 0;
  const tempo = 1.0;

  window.alert('22222')

  const notes = {};
  
  const player = new MidiPlayer.Player(function (event) {
    if (event.name === "Note on") {
      const note = instrument.play(
        event.noteNumber + transpose,
        ac.currentTime,
        {
          gain: event.velocity / 100,
        }
      );
      notes[event.noteNumber + transpose] = note;
    }
    if (event.name === "Note off") {
      notes[event.noteNumber + transpose]?.stop();
    }
    if (event.name === "Set Tempo") {
      player.setTempo(event.data * tempo);
    }
  });

  player.loadDataUri(data);
  player.play();
  true;
};
```

My html file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>My First Parcel App</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="Play()">Play</button>
  <script type="module" src="player.player"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The files hierarchy:

[image]

Now in my `App.tsx` I have the following code:

```
let initiateSource =
  Platform.OS === 'ios'
    ? require('./html/Web.bundle/player/index.html')
    : {
        uri: 'file:///android_asset/player/index.html',
        baseurl: 'file:///android_asset/player',
      };

const App = () => {
  const webviewRef = useRef<WebView>(null);

  const injectJS = `
  
setTimeout(function() {
  let button = document.querySelectorAll('button')[0];
  button.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';
  window.Play()
  true;
}, 1)
  `;

  setTimeout(() => {
    webviewRef.current?.injectJavaScript(injectJS);
  }, 3000);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
      <WebView
        ref={webviewRef}
        onMessage={() => {}}
        source={initiateSource}
        style={{flex: 1, marginTop: 50}}
        javaScriptEnabled
        originWhitelist={['*']}
        allowFileAccess
        scalesPageToFit
        allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs
        allowFileAccessFromFileURLs
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

**What am I trying to achieve is to call the `window.Play()` function after rendering**
but it's not called. The `html` is shown inside the `WebView` and even then if I click on the button, won't call the method.

If I run the ReactJS project alone, will work as expected, but not in the `WebView`.

Note: my file is called `player.player` and not `player.js` because will throw an error about unresolved extensions and I added

```
resolver: {
  assetExts: [...defaultConfig.resolver.assetExts, "player"],
},
```

inside `metro.config.js` so it will run as expected.

**What am I doing wrong here?**

Thank you for your time!

### EDIT

So I tried to add my whole `player.player` code as a function inside a `<script></script>` (the imports, declarations, Play function etc) so I would have all the stuff in `index.html` but still not working